# Problem in loading layout on order success page due custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, order-email

I have created a custom module for sending order email to customer on order success.

my config.xml file :

```
...
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <company_customizeorderemail_checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                    <class>Company_CustomizeOrderEmail_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>send_order_email</method>
                </company_customizeorderemail_checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
...
```

My observer file has function as following :

```
public function send_order_email($observer)
    {
        try
        {

            $order_ids = $observer->getData('order_ids'); 
            $order_id = $order_ids[0];


            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);

            /* send new order email */              
            $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

this module send email on order success but `order success page` showing page content on white page, it means there is problem in loading layout.

What is the problem in my custom module?

Or Is there any another method to send order email?

Answer (score 0):

I have check your code, find that few code may be create issue.

- Have you declare the class of
  `Company_CustomizeOrderEmail_Model_Observer`, if not then not then you
  define the class bcoz as per as, ***your code at `observer.php`, you did not declare class***.
- For getting order id, you need to use:
      `$order_ids = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order_ids');`
  **instead** of
      `$order_ids = $observer->getData('order_ids');`

Comment: Thanks For Reply, but I have declared class in observer.php and the code `$observer->getData('order_ids')` working, it return correct order_id so that functioning is perfect, problem is in page layout. Please reply.

Comment: renove the observer code from config.xml and check that  success page ok or not?

Comment: Yes, after removing event from config.xml success page showing correct. this module only created for this one task. What do I do?

Comment: PLease remove "$order->getSendConfirmation(null);
                $order->sendNewOrderEmail();"

Comment: check that what will happne

Comment: This time also success page showing correct layout.

Comment: getSendConfirmation is not magento default function.That may be create issue

Comment: How to send order email?

Comment: sendNewOrderEmail() use to new order email

Comment: See my edit code, when I try after comment `$order->getSendConfirmation(null);` also facing problem of layout.